# M joining tables

Tags: mysql

I have one table called county and another called population.

The county table has 4 fields called; `county` `province` `grant` and `area`.

The population table has 3 fields called `county` `year` `population`.

I need to join to the two tables so that i can get the average population for each province for each year.

this is what i have so far:

```
SELECT counties.Province, AVG(population.Population) 
FROM population 
JOIN counties 
  ON population.County = counties.County 
GROUP BY counties.Province ASC.
```

This only shows the average all together and not through each year. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I guess you mean 4 fields, not four records/rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the Year on the `GROUP` .

```
SELECT counties.Province, population.year,  AVG(population.Population) 
FROM population 
JOIN counties 
  ON population.County = counties.County 
GROUP BY counties.Province, population.year
```